# Disjunctive normal form of (¬(p → q) → (q ∧ ¬r))

Tags: propositional-calculus, disjunctive-normal-form

I learning how to convert to disjunctive normal forms, I have the following,

```
(¬(p → q) → (q ∧ ¬r))
```

I understand any p→q can be represented as (¬p)∨q, therefore if I image the above as just that I can break each section down, resulting in:

```
1. p → q == (¬p)∨ q, therefore (¬(p → q) == ¬((¬p) ∨ q
2. ¬((¬p) ∨ q → (q ∧ ¬r)) == ¬(¬((¬p)∨q)) ∨ (q ∧ ¬r )

Therefore the disjunctive form is:
¬(¬((¬p)∨q)) ∨ (q ∧ ¬r )
```

The truth table for this seems to match, is this correct? I have a feeling I have left a step out, maybe repetition of the NOT could be fixed?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo from my textbook "Any logical expression can be written as the sequence of or's of its min-terms. A min-term is an and of all the input variables. An expression written in this form is said to be in disjunctive normal form."

Comment: Yes, the repetition of two NOTs can be cancelled : $\lnot (\lnot \varphi) \equiv \varphi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\neg(p\Rightarrow q) \Leftrightarrow \neg(\neg p\vee q)$

and so

$\neg(p\Rightarrow q) \Rightarrow  (q\wedge \neg r)$

is equivalent to

$\neg(\neg(\neg p\vee q)) \vee  (q\wedge \neg r)$

is equivalent to

$(\neg p\vee q)\vee  (q\wedge \neg r)$

is equivalent to

$\neg p\vee q \vee  (q\wedge \neg r)$.

By absorption $a\vee (a\wedge b) \Leftrightarrow a$, it is equivalent to

$\neg p\vee q$.

Answer (score 1):

Using [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org):

```
>>> from sympy import * 
>>> p, q, r = symbols('p q r')
>>> phi = Not(p >> q) >> (q & Not(r))
```

Converting to DNF and simplifying:

```
>>> to_dnf(phi, simplify=False)
q | ~p | (q & ~r)
>>> to_dnf(phi, simplify=True)
q | ~p
```

Hence, we have the DNF formulas

$$q \vee \left(q \wedge \neg r\right) \vee \neg p \equiv q \vee \neg p$$